# Google OAuth2 redirect_url

Tags: google-oauth

I'm unclear about how OAuth2 (or at least google's implementation of it) works for server applications as far as `redirect_url` is concerned.

I'm trying to achieve three use cases:

Case 1:

1. A user who has never logged in logs in through my web interface using the well-documented tools found in the google identity management API, which produces a token.
2. My javascript client sends the resulting token along with username (or anything else needed) to the server.
3. The server uses the token and additional information to make sure the user is authenticated and has access to some resource that is requested, for instance basic login.

Case 2:

1. A user has already logged via web page and their token is available as a cookie that has not expired, and the initial page forwards that to the same token checking mechanism as above.
2. The server uses the token to validate their session.

Case 3:

1. A user is accessing my server from an app (like Unity or some other compiled Qt application or even on a command line) and is prompted for credentials because no token can/should exist when cookies aren't a thing in this context.
2. If their credentials are no good, the application says so, and asks for new ones.
3. If the credentials are good, a token is generated but is probably not used except if the token needs to be refreshed at some time interval, because we assume that re-running the app or command line is effectively a new session.

None one of these cases requires my server to use the `redirect_url` (except maybe the case of #2 where the token is expired), because:

Case 1, the user would have been unable to pass a token in the first place if they can't log in, and would have been redirected before that.

Case 2, the server accepts the token and doesn't redirect, or rejects the token and only then may redirect them back to the initial state of Case 1, but the server already wants to redirect them because the token is invalid, so I don't need/want the `redirect_url` from oauth.

Case 3, we are assuming there is no browser and don't care about `redirect_url` in any case no matter what.

As my code works now, using: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server there is always this `redirect_url` field which I don't know what to do with, and when I execute REST commands I'm getting raw html back which includes self-submitting javascript instead of useful headers.

I can see a case for exposing some URL on my server to validate an oauth2 session/token from google during authentication, for instance, but that would be a validation url, not a `redirect_url`, because the user/server doesn't "go" to that url at that point in the process.

So, I don't know what to do with `redirect_url` because when I leave it out, things don't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot going on in this question, so I don't really know the type of answer you're looking for. I wrote our code for [authenticating our Qt app with Google SSO](https://appfluence.com/productivity/how-to-authenticate-qt-google-sso/), and wrote the linked post discussing the problems we faced.

One thing I found confusing in the documentation and provided examples is that when defining an app in the Google console, if your client is a desktop one, there's no field for redirection URLs. Instead, the client specifies it when initiating the authentication flow, and then it's expected to open a transient server that listens for the return connection from the Google side. There's no point declaring it on the Google console because it cannot be validated unless the client app is running at the moment, and even then, it's typically a hardcoded URL like http://127.0.0.1:1234/ as you would expect.